# Explain "griefing" attack on Aave flash loan

Tags: security, flash-loans, aave

[Aave doc about flash loan](https://docs.aave.com/developers/guides/flash-loans) warns to never store funds inside a receiver contract as it can be exposed to "griefing" attack.

So my questions are

1. Can you give an example of this attack?
2. How can funds be stored, when they need to be returned in the same transaction?

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Developer @ Aave here, good questions.

1. It depends on your contract. But a simple one would be:

- Contract A has funds and the `executeOperation()`
- Contract B calls `flashloan()`, passing in Contract A as the `receiverAddress`
- Contract A now executes `executeOperation()`
- Contract A repays the flash loaned amount and debt as designed

The attack would be an attacker contract also passing in Contract A as the  `receiverAddress`.

2. In the above example, if you are doing profitable arbitrage trades with flash loans, it is possible that you're leaving profits on Contract A. So the flash loaned amount is returned, but your profit remain in the contract (if you don't actively transfer them out).

Comment: Why is this an attack though? If Contract A is meant to be an arbitrage bot, then its `executeOperation()` should only terminate if the operation results in net positive gains, right? So even if Contract B calls `flashloan()`, giving Contract A's address, is there a way for Contract A to actually lose funds?

Comment: You could have a positive arbitrage but flashloan fees are larger than the arbitrage. Yes you can write boilerplate code to check but it wastes gas and isn't straightforward/intuitive

Answer (score 2):

I think the things is: anyone can call the function in contract A means anyone can utilize the funds inside the contract. This can finally used up the funds and it is called a griefing attack.